# How do you change the colour of Twitter's Bootstrap CSS?

Tags: css, less, twitter-bootstrap

I've not used less before today.

I changed the colour in preboot.less to:

```
// Color Scheme
@baseColor:         @orange;                  // Set a base color
```

I then complied the less files.  It all came out, but everything was still blue.

So I tried the js.less route.  Still blue.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a bootstrap theme generator that works from a picture.... So you can just take a picture of your "old" website, upload it here, and it'll generate a theme that matches your old color scheme!

**Note: This site appears to be offline at the moment. If you still want this feature, [you can install the site from it's Github repo](https://github.com/mquan/lavish), and try it from there.**

http://www.lavishbootstrap.com/

and of course Bootstrap itself allows you to customize the colors when you download it now, but that involves lots of cutting and pasting of color schemes.... The tool above figures it all out for you...

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: The website for Lavish Bootstrap is dead at the moment (still worked in August, 2015). The new official Bootstrap customizer is located at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 4):

You might find the [Bootstrap Generator](http://www.martinbean.co.uk/bootstrap-generator/) useful - it lets you choose colours etc and generates a compiled Boostrap CSS file for you.

Comment: this should be used for version 2: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html

Comment: Yes, it is. Must have changed in the past 2+ years.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 2.0-wip version, this is the deal.

the .primary class uses the @blue and @blueDark variables for creating the button's gradient. Those variables are set in the variables.less file.

In the buttons.less file, the other button classes are hard-coded with hex values.

```
// Danger and error appear as red
  &.danger {
    .gradientBar(#ee5f5b, #c43c35);
  }
  // Success appears as green
  &.success {
    .gradientBar(#62c462, #57a957);
  }
  // Info appears as a neutral blue
  &.info {
    .gradientBar(#5bc0de, #339bb9);
  }
```

You have to change those hex values or create variables that you replace the hex values with. I'm new to using bootstrap from twitter myself, but this appears to be the situation.

Comment: could it be achieve without less? I installed less, change something, then got tons of compile errors...

Comment: I have essentially stopped using Less also because of the errors. If you do that you have to edit the different classes in the boostrap.css file or where ever you are putting all the CSS from bootstrap. You have to edit all the classes directly in the CSS. In 2.0=wip the button classes are .btn, .primary, .info, .danger I think. In the final release they are found here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the `@orange` variable to a color, like this

`@orange: #FF2400;`

Comment: That was done already.   Turns out the button colour and links are all based off their own variables, and don't use @baseColor yet..

Answer (score 0):

This one for the #01a4d9 color btn

```
.btn {
    border-color:#c5c5c5;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 }

.btn-primary {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    background-color:#007cc5;
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #01a4d9, #0193c5);
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#01a4d9),  to(#0193c5));
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #01a4d9, #0193c5);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #01a4d9, #0193c5);
    background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #01a4d9, #0193c5);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0096c5', endColorstr='#ff0054c5', GradientType=0);
    border-color:#0193c5 #0193c5 #003479;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    *background-color:#0193c5;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
 }

.btn-primary:hover,.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active,.btn-primary.disabled,.btn-primary[disabled] {
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color:#0193c5;
    *background-color:#0049ac;
 }

.btn-primary:active,.btn-primary.active {
    background-color:#003f92 \9;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the color of your links and .btn-primary (which is what I think the question was referring to), adjust the @linkColor:

```
@linkColor: @orange;
```